# User is getting logged out after changing password

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a view that allows user to change password.I do not want to use default password authentication system.When a user changes his password,the password is successfully changed but the user is getting logged out.I saw that session is getting invalidated on password change.I do not want to login again after password change.So how to retain session after password change?

my views.py file,

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_password = request.POST.get('pwd') 
        user=request.user  
        try:  
            u = User.objects.get(username=user)
            u.set_password(new_password)
            u.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request,user)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Password successfully changed')   
            return redirect("password_change") 
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'User Does not exist')   
    else:
        return render(request,"password_change.html",{})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use variable u in update_session_auth_hash. You are using "user" from request, which still has the old password.